# CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr() modifies java system.out stream

Tags: java, logging, crystal-reports, outputstream, business-objects

I have a JBoss EAP 6.4.8 and a statless EJB which does nothing more than getting an ISessionMgr instance.

```
public boolean changePassword(String user, String oldPw, String newPw, String cmsName, String authType)
{
    boolean success = false;
    try
    {
        System.out.println("BEFORE");
        ISessionMgr sessionMgr = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();
        System.out.println("AFTER");

        // commented out
        // IEnterpriseSession session = sessionMgr.logon(user, oldPw, cmsName, authType);
        // session.getUserInfo().setPassword(oldPw, newPw);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
        LOG.error("Error changing password for BO-CMS and user '" + user + "'", e);
    }
    return success;
}
```

The original task of this EJB was to change a user password which works perfectly fine.
However, I noticed that after calling CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr() each System.out (and each log4j Logger as well) produces no output anymore.
The code above prints only 'BEFORE' and no "AFTER" or "EXCEPTION"
But my debugger proves that System.out.println("AFTER") gets invoked.

By the way: calling, calling this piece of code directly from within a java main method works as expected.
I get an "BEFORE" and "AFTER" output.

Does anybody know what happens here?